# dplyr: How to sum a grouped column A by condition of column B and mutate to colum sum_A without NA

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, conditional-statements

I try to sum column A within each group only if column B==1 and mutate it to column sum_A.
But in column sum_A *NA* is shown where B == 0. How can I overcome this? Many thanks!

Output of my code:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

My code:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(A = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 5, 4.4, 
4.9), B = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), group = c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

df <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%  
  mutate(sum_A = case_when(B==1 ~ sum(A)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `fill` on those groups having a non-NA elementin 'sum_A', then replace the NAs with 0 (`replace_na`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%  
  mutate(sum_A = case_when(B==1 ~ sum(A))) %>% 
  fill(sum_A, .direction = 'downup') %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(sum_A = replace_na(sum_A, 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#      A     B group sum_A
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1   5.1     1     1  10  
# 2   4.9     1     1  10  
# 3   4.7     0     2   0  
# 4   4.6     0     2   0  
# 5   5       0     3  10.4
# 6   5.4     1     3  10.4
# 7   4.6     1     4   9.6
# 8   5       0     4   9.6
# 9   4.4     1     5   9.3
#10   4.9     1     5   9.3
```